# How to update timestamp with mysql foreign key constraint on update cascade?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

1. items
2. items_details

If tabel 2 updates it's content, I want the timestamp (change on update) within tabel 1 updated.

Therefore I definded in MySql foreign key constraint on update cascade within table 2. This somehow has no effect at all.

How can the timestamp of table 1 be updated if the content in table 2 changes?

Comment: It can be done by using triggers, not foreign key constraints. You should read what FK constraints actually do, because they're not used to update a timestamp column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an after update trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER items_details_after_update
AFTER UPDATE
ON items_details FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE items
    SET timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE NEW.item_id = id;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

This answer assumes that there exists a column `item_id` in the `item_details` table, which is a foreign key pointing to a primary key `id` column in the parent `items` table.

Comment: Interesting, thank you that seems to work. What does the keyword "NEW" do?

Comment: @merlin `NEW` is a special variable in the trigger which represents the record which was updated, in the state after the update.